# not able to select option from chosen multiple select after sorting

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using chosen.jquery to convert my select to multiple select. not able to select  option from chosen multiple select after sorting.

Following is my sort method. after sorting I call trigger api.

```
     function sortSelect(fieldObj) {
var selElem = document.getElementById('partnerCasteId');
var tmpAry = new Array();  var j = 0;
for (var i=0;i<selElem.options.length;i++) {  

    if(selElem.options[i].value != "")
    {  
        tmpAry[j] = new Array();
        tmpAry[j]  = selElem.options[i].text;
        j = j + 1;

    }
}  
tmpAry.sort();   

 var i = tmpAry.length-2, prev='';
 do {  
     if (tmpAry[i] === prev) { 
        tmpAry.splice(i,1);
     }
     prev = tmpAry[i];
 } while (i-- && i>-1);


while (selElem.options.length > 0) {
    selElem.options[0] = null;
}

for (var i=0;i<tmpAry.length;i++) {

    var op = new Option(tmpAry[i], tmpAry[i]);
    selElem.options[i] = op;
  }
  return;   
}

 $("#partnerCasteId").trigger('chosen:updated');
```

Comment: Please add js fiddle example

Comment: Here you go. Thanks https://jsfiddle.net/ParagCool/bsf877ko/10/

Comment: I debugged chosen.jquery and found that at following line the selected drop down value vanishes.                                              if (this.is_multiple || this.form_field.selectedIndex !== this.current_selectedIndex) {  
          this.form_field_jq.trigger("change", {
            'selected': this.form_field.options[item.options_index].value
          });
        }

Comment: Please let me know as I really have to finish my work.

Comment: I found the issue. I was calling same chosen function for both the drop downs.